# Get time spent by field (column) on Jira

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I have a board with 3 columns (To-do, Work in Progress and Done). 
Is there a way to get the time spent by a card on each column via API?

The [getIssue](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/issue-getIssue) does not fetch this kind of data

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'time spent by' measure available through the JIRA REST API (as it is too narrow/specific).

There is a possibility to get timestamps of status changes via REST API though. As [this](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/API-for-get-transition-and-history-for-issues-by-REST-API/qaq-p/503108#M40767) answer explains it, you need to use `&expand=changelog` flag in your API request. In this case response would return `created` field for each transition that issue has made. You can use it to calculate time between issue transitions.

There is [another answer](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Is-it-possible-to-get-the-issue-history-using-the-REST-API/qaq-p/510094#M47754) that explains how to get dates using `jira-python` library (just in case you use it).

Comment: even the date when the card has been moved?

Comment: nice! with changelog parameter I can handle it :)